# Return HashMap type from function

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In the following function, I am creating a new HashMap with entries from a file (divided in name & value -> I am trying to read a meminfo file from Linux). I am stuck on how to return the values of the hashmap.
Am I approaching this in the right way or should this be done differently?

```
fn read_file_to_hashmap(file_name: impl AsRef<Path>) -> HashMap<String, String> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(&file_name).expect("error here"));

    let hash_map = ["name", "value"]
        .into_iter()
        .zip(file.lines().map(Result::unwrap))
        .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();
    return hash_map;
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
    error[E0308]: mismatched types
--> src/main.rs:15:12
|
8  | fn read_file_to_hashmap(file_name: impl AsRef<Path>) -> HashMap<String, String> {
|                                                         ----------------------- expected `HashMap<std::string::String, std::string::String>` because of return type
...
15 |     return hash_map;
|            ^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found `&str`
|
= note: expected struct `HashMap<std::string::String, _>`
            found struct `HashMap<&str, _>`
```

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is. Your function currently returns the hashmap, doesn't it?

Comment: Show us the result of running a unit test, please, which attempts to de-reference the `["MemFree"]` value. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example As written, there is apparently nothing wrong, you report zero symptoms that need to be repaired.

Comment: Hi all, I edited the post. Rookie mistake, sorry for that!
Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string literal "foo" is a `&'static str`. In your case, "name" and "value" has type `&str`, but you need `String`. So just convert it to `String` by using `.to_string()` on `&str`.

```
fn read_file_to_hashmap(file_name: impl AsRef<Path>) -> HashMap<String, String> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(&file_name).expect("error here"));

    let hash_map = ["name".to_string(), "value".to_string()]
        .into_iter()
        .zip(file.lines().map(Result::unwrap))
        .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();
    return hash_map;
}
```