# Converting a text file to a hashmap dictionary

Tags: file, rust, hashmap

I already [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73818389/return-hashmap-type-from-function?noredirect=1#comment130356003_73818389) a problem linked to this code, but it appears to be a different problem.
I will try to describe the problem as clearly as possible.

**Goal that I want to achieve**

Create a hashmap with contents from a text file (in this case /proc/meminfo), similar to this format:

```
{   
"MemTotal":       "16256760 kB",
"MemFree":          "462276 kB",
"MemAvailable":   "10108672 kB",
"Buffers":         "1432356 kB",
"Cached":          "7138456 kB",
... etc
}
```

The raw output from the text file looks like this:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       16256760 kB
MemFree:         2685512 kB
MemAvailable:   11105752 kB
Buffers:          774076 kB
Cached:          7722948 kB
... etc
```

The number of lines should be depending on how many lines a file contains.

**Current situation**

The code I currently have will create a hashmap with:

- key: "entryx".
- value: a line from the text file.

Code:

```
fn read_file_to_hashmap(path: impl AsRef<Path>) -> HashMap<String, String> {
let reader = BufReader::new(File::open(path).expect("error here"));

let hashmap = [
    "Entry1".to_string(),
    "Entry2".to_string(),
    "Entry3".to_string(),
    "Entry4".to_string(),
    "Entry5".to_string(),
]
.into_iter()
.zip(reader.lines().map(Result::unwrap))
.collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();
return hashmap;
}
```

println! output:

```
{
"Entry1": "MemTotal:       16256760 kB",
"Entry5": "Cached:          7138456 kB",
"Entry2": "MemFree:          462276 kB",
"Entry4": "Buffers:         1432356 kB",
"Entry3": "MemAvailable:   10108672 kB",
}
```

How can I change the code to achieve the desired goal?

Comment: Your probably need some deserialization code. Try https://docs.rs/serde-json.

Comment: You need to parse your individual lines, rather than have a static (and nonsensical) list of entries. That means using something like `str::split(_once)`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman most device files have completely ad-hoc format, I doubt serde has deserializer implementations for all of them (if it has any at all).

Comment: I'd advice [`nom`](https://crates.io/crates/nom) as a universal parser for these types of things.

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it a little, the easiest in your case is probably regular expressions. For example, this regex would match: https://regex101.com/r/j4KXxv/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are many ways to solve this problem, I think the easiest in this case would be a [regular expression](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/).

In your case, this regular expression should [perform what you want](https://regex101.com/r/wWvBoJ/1):

```
^(\S+):\s+(.+)$
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the line (if `multi_line` is enabled)
- `(\S+)` matches one or more non-whitespace characters
- `:\s+` matches `:` followed by at least one whitespace character
- `(.+)` matches everything left over
- `$` matches the end of the line (if `multi_line` is enabled)

Written in a program, this is how it looks:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

use regex::RegexBuilder;

fn main() {
    let meminfo_str = std::fs::read_to_string("/proc/meminfo").unwrap();

    let re = RegexBuilder::new(r"^(\S+):\s+(.+)$")
        .multi_line(true)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let meminfo = re
        .captures_iter(&meminfo_str)
        .map(|cap| {
            (
                cap.get(1).unwrap().as_str().to_string(),
                cap.get(2).unwrap().as_str().to_string(),
            )
        })
        .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();

    println!("{:#?}", meminfo);
}
```

```
{
    "SwapTotal": "3145728 kB",
    "Slab": "133492 kB",
    "SwapFree": "3145728 kB",
    "Writeback": "0 kB",
    "Mapped": "120212 kB",
    "SReclaimable": "99628 kB",
    "KernelStack": "7616 kB",
    "WritebackTmp": "0 kB",
    "VmallocChunk": "0 kB",
    "AnonHugePages": "1914880 kB",
    "Active(file)": "1187412 kB",
    "Mlocked": "0 kB",
    "ShmemHugePages": "0 kB",
    "FileHugePages": "0 kB",
    "MemTotal": "10129324 kB",
    "Buffers": "143812 kB",
    "HugePages_Total": "0",
    "HugePages_Surp": "0",
    "DirectMap4k": "68608 kB",
    "Inactive(file)": "1245252 kB",
    "Inactive": "3928204 kB",
    "CommitLimit": "8210388 kB",
    "Unevictable": "0 kB",
    "AnonPages": "2637672 kB",
    "Active(anon)": "448 kB",
    "SUnreclaim": "33864 kB",
    "MemAvailable": "6891192 kB",
    "KReclaimable": "99628 kB",
    "Committed_AS": "2777120 kB",
    "Hugepagesize": "2048 kB",
    "VmallocUsed": "27996 kB",
    "SwapCached": "0 kB",
    "Active": "1187860 kB",
    "HugePages_Rsvd": "0",
    "ShmemPmdMapped": "0 kB",
    "FilePmdMapped": "0 kB",
    "Cached": "2306060 kB",
    "VmallocTotal": "34359738367 kB",
    "DirectMap2M": "7206912 kB",
    "Hugetlb": "0 kB",
    "Inactive(anon)": "2682952 kB",
    "Dirty": "19460 kB",
    "PageTables": "24792 kB",
    "Bounce": "0 kB",
    "Percpu": "1392 kB",
    "Shmem": "17328 kB",
    "MemFree": "4633364 kB",
    "HugePages_Free": "0",
    "DirectMap1G": "12582912 kB",
    "NFS_Unstable": "0 kB",
}
```

---

If you want to be more robust and parse correctly even if there might be whitespace at the end or beginning of a line, you could use this regex instead:

```
^\s*(\S+):\s+(\S.+\S)\s*$
```

Comment: Very interesting to see how regular expression works! Thank you a lot for helping me out.

Quick advice-related question: I see that my post has a negative rating, do you have tips on how to improve my questions in the future?

Comment: That's the first time someone has asked me that question, and I respect that you do :) sadly, I don't really know. I don't really find your question to be bad. Maybe people think you should have tried harder to solve it yourself before asking here, but I think your code shows some effort from your side. I really don't know. It happened to me as well in the past for no apparent reason. Maybe the title of your question is to generic, and you should have asked how to parse `/proc/meminfo` instead.